# How to tell whether an Observable is "awaiting" another with RxJS (for Ajax request indicator, for example)

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

While learning RxJS, I'm wondering:

How to create an Observable that tells whether Observable X has had value after Observable Y?

Example need would be to tell whether there is an Ajax request pending response? Like awaiting with [Bacon.js](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While formulating the question, I found one answer:

- map (select within RxJS) another Observable (the one triggering the request) to true
- map another Observable (response one) to false
- merge

i.e.

```
var availabilityPending = usernameToValidate.select(function() {return true;})
         .merge(usernameAvailable.select(function() {return false;}));
```

Don't know if there's already a helper for this kind of behaviour?